# In the US, is there a documentable difference in musical genre preference between Democrats and Republicans?

Tags: united-states, media

As far as I know, political parties favour some [music genres](http://www.musicgenreslist.com/) more than others to sell their outlook and policies. Or at least I never heard classical music or death metal being used.

*Which music genres are used most extensively by political parties?*

*Do these differ by party?*

Comment: This is really a marketing question more than politics. It's all about targeting particular demographics.

Comment: @DA Sort of. But then what is the Heart of politics? The demos? => Demographics. Politics, as packaged into parties, is nothing but targeting demographics. Although the written word and speech are given more conscious recognition than music; despite the trend of music going back to oldest palaeolithic tribal roots and "this chieftain is cool".

Comment: That's true. In this case, I think we'd find that the demographics aren't so much rep vs. dem but niches within each broader demographic.

Comment: @DA. Still, I'll keep this question open for the floor; as it's not dissimilar to questions about political speech-writing.

Comment: Could also be useful for that freshman College Republican/Democrat needing help with their mix tape for that one girl that shows up at the meetings and sits in the 3rd row...

Comment: In the United States or world wide?  I would suggest limiting the scope of the question to a particular question.

Comment: @AffableGeek Thanks :-) The USA will suffice; as it has the largest media market.

Comment: I've heard a few of the right-wing bands, but I didn't like what I heard. I'm based in Sweden. We have a similar phenomenon in Sweden. All good bands are on the left side, while the rightwing bands usually are quite boring. Actually, a lot rightwing politicians listen to leftwing music.

Comment: @DA. - "Mix Tape"? You should be aware that modern hip kids all switched to cutting CD compilations!

Comment: "political parties favour some music genres more than others to sell their outlook" - no, not really. It's vice versa - political parties attract people who already self-selected into liking specific genres, usually by geographic and age slices. Not to mention that most Country music (that Avi's answer claims is the domain of the right) is all about aching-breaking heart and carries no political outlook whatsoever. So for that matter was most of (at least, early) Beatles and virtually all Elvis.

Comment: @DVK Meh. These fandangled optical-magnetic devices; I prefer wax phonograph cylinders.

Comment: @DVK Interesting. If so, do we know why? Could there be an answer in that, if anyone's looked into it?

Comment: @LateralFractal - simple version: old fogeys like old music. They also tend rightish. You will note that conservatives in 1960s would be EXTREMELY anti-Elvis (some for political reason). Now that today's conservatives get to choose between Elvis (who they grew up with) and Lady GaGa...

Comment: ... and R-heavy demographics likes country music because that's the right music for demographics (rural USA), AND the only genre that's not at least partially left wing (aside from those Bush-dissing singers whose name escapes me).

Comment: Yes, I think that's the key point. It's not political leanings that drives their taste in music. It's just that their taste in music parallels their particular demographic, which happens to parallel the political party demographics.

Comment: *We got both genres, country and western*.

Comment: Important for this question: Correlation doesn't imply causation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Apparently](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/facebooks-like-button-separates-democrats-from-republicans-2014-10-28). A comparison of bands "Liked" on Facebook and the political affiliation of the Facebook profile found that some music was more usually liked by Democrats and other music more by Republicans.

[image: Musical preference by party]
<sub>(source: [marketwatch.com](http://ei.marketwatch.com//Multimedia/2014/10/28/Photos/NS/MW-CX685_fbelec_20141028142409_NS.jpg?uuid=ad3da966-5ecf-11e4-bd36-cfb71039ab6b))</sub>

As you can see from this graph, members of  *<< your preferred party >>* have far superior musical taste, preferring such talented artists as *<< band you like >>*, whereas *<< opposed political party >>* lacks taste entirely, preferring talentless hacks like *<< band you hate >>*.

Analysis of data from [Echo Nest](https://web.archive.org/web/20161214053111/http://notes.variogr.am:80/post/26869688460/how-well-does-music-predict-your-politics), an API that provides data about music, also found differences in the preferences of Democrats and Republicans. Analysis of Echo Nest data found that Republicans had less diverse musical tastes.

However, the findings of Echo Nest seemed to contract analysis of Facebook likes. For example, Democrats consistently like The Beatles on Facebook, but Echo Nest found that the Beatles did not have a strong partisan association. So, while there seems to be a difference, it is not clear what that difference is. A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=republicans%20democrats%20music) will turn up a whole number of analyses finding differences between the musical tastes of Democrats and Republicans.

Comment: AC/DC: BRINGING THE PEOPLE TOGETHER!

Comment: Clearly it's Journey around which everyone can rally, you damned commie.

Comment: @DA. Naturally. It has AC and DC. ;-)

Comment: I haven't even heard of most on the right, and I'm in England. That's actually really interesting.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - same here. I have actually *never heard* of any of the bands in the lightest pink (except perhaps "Ted Nugent" - but I had no idea it/they were a band/musician), whereas I have heard of and heard the music of all the others except Nickleback and Sugarland. I am also based in England. Weird.

Comment: My British friends, isn't it obvious? I've never heard of them either (Australia here), but surely those pale pinks must be Country Music.

Comment: MGOwen is correct, Brits. The light pink is all country music. What shocks me is the placement of the Beatles. I've always seen them as one of those bands just about everybody loves. I guess it's that commie John Lennon.

Comment: @TenthJustice Pure selection bias. Most people who bother to post their favorite musicians on Facebook are younger, not older. Most people under 35 (to define a group young enough to have had to basically "seek out" The Beatles) who not just like the Beatles but actively list them as their favorite music are (apparently) more likely to be Democrats. I'm sure a poll of 55-65 year olds about their love of the Beatles and their politics would show them closer to the middle.

Comment: @KyleHale - I'd say the whole thing is so prone to self-selection bias as to be useless. I don't know a single right wing person who didn't like Queen (OTOH, Metallica? come on). Of course, the fact that EMINEM and Taylor Swift are equally liked simply proves the popular 3rd party thesis that both Democrats and Republicans are equally useless and morally corrupt

Comment: @DVK Interestingly, if a band is equally hated - would it also end up in the middle?

Comment: @LateralFractal - I have one word for you. Justin Bieber.

Comment: If everyone hates it, it won't be on the list. I don't see Bieber up there, but then most of his fans aren't going to be political.